# Convert Embedded JSON Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have an embedded set of data given to me which needs to be converted to a pandas Dataframe

```
"{'rows':{'data':[[{'column_name':'column','row_value':value}]]}"
```

It's just a snippet of what it looks like at the start. Everything inside data repeats over and over. i.e.

```
{‘column_name’:’name’, ’row_value :value }
```

I want the values of column_name to be the column headings. And the values of row_value to be the values in each row.

Ive tried a few different ways. I thought it would be something along the lines of

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[data_rows['row_value'] for data_rows in raw_data['rows']['data']], columns=['column_name'])
```

But I might be way off. I probably not stepping into the data right with raw_data['rows']['data']

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: How is your data enclosed?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I just updated it to be more accurate. Its actually enclosed in quotes which i've only now just noticed. So I know at least I have to remove those now first.

Comment: Why there are tow `rows` in the dictionary?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh typo. My bad. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another loop in your list comprehension to get elements out:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[data_row for data_rows in raw_data['rows']['data'] for data_row in data_rows])
```

```
print(df)

                  name value  type
0  dynamic_tag_tracker  null  null
```

Comment: Just made one last update to JSON to make it simpler looking. Tried something similar to what you have, but no luck. I am assuming I need to remove the quotes first before doing processing.

Comment: @JackGruber If you couldn't do `raw_data['rows']['data']`, you can try to convert your data to dictionary with `raw_data = ast.literal_eval(raw_data)` first.